# MySQL: Is there an easy way to convert UUID into an integer?

Tags: mysql, uuid

I need to transfer data from one system A to system B. System A stores user ids are UUID and system B stores them as integers.

I am using MySQL select statement to retrieve and save data from System A and then transferring it across to System B. Is there an easy way to convert UUID into an integer in MySQL select statement?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563502/uuid-to-unique-integer-id

Comment: Are you talking about 128-bit UUIDs as per RFC4122?  Yes: if you have a 128-bit integer, you can store it in an integer.  You could also use two 64-bit integers or four 32-bit integers.  You can also store them as a string.

Comment: @paddy, The UUID I'm talking about is something like this: 002D0BF8-8AA3-120D-A933-6DDE51F15329. There are few rows of data already in System B. When I tried to insert the UUID values in System B, it complains that there are duplicate items already there. I cannot really delete the data that already in System B. I can however add say a constant value to UUID (say 300) so that it does not conflict with the data in System B but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was talking about as well.  It represents 16 bytes, or 128-bits.  Are you wishing to squash a 128-bit integer into a 32-bit integer?

Comment: @paddy, Sorry I'm not really understanding this. The System B has int(10) unsigned, which I don't want to change. Isn't this 4 bytes? So the challenge is to fit UUID conversion from System A to translate into System B.

Comment: So yes what you are saying is right. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I have written an answer for you.  I think we all interpreted the question wrong, or it was the wrong question to ask.  You can of course translate your values from one system to another if you provide some form of mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in comments, you cannot simply turn a UUID into an integer and expect it to be unique.  A UUID is 128-bits, versus `INT(10)` which is probably 32-bits.  This means you have to ignore 96 bits, which equates to a very large number of potential collisions (around 78 octillion different UUIDs for every unique 32-bit value).

Not all is lost, because in 32 bits you can represent up to around 4 billion users and that's probably enough.  All you really need to do is map your existing UUIDs to an integer, and that's actually quite straight-forward.

To achieve this, you can make a translation table that stores both UUID (as the primary key) and a unique integer (perhaps an auto-increment field).  You can use this to map from System A to System B (and *vice versa*).  You can put this table into either of the two databases, or you can keep it separate.  Personally, I would put it into System B, because that is where the `userId` integer values actually make sense.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes your solution seems to work fine. I cannot put the translation table in System B. I can create a translation table in System A and that should work fine. I was wondering if it is possible to use sub-queries to do the mapping in System A itself (instead of creating a new table). I couldn't think of a way to do this. Any idea?

Comment: Why don't you just put an extra field in the user table of System A?  Something like `system_b_user_id`, and make a `UNIQUE` constraint on it of course.